# Formar array con agregacion en MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Tengo un documento en MongoDB 3.4 con la siguiente estructura:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e3419e468d01013eadb83dc"),
    "id_station" : "62",
    "fiware_service" : null,
    "fiware_servicepath" : null,
    "id_fiware_name" : "CE_del_medio",
    "attrName" : "15",
    "attrType" : "float",
    "attrValue" : 0.33,
    "id_sensor_station_absolute" : "15_62",
    "recvTimeTs" : 1580387045,
    "recvTime" : "2020-01-30T12:24:05.00Z",
    "id_fiware" : "15",
    "sensor_type" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "id",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "15"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "img",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "assets/img/contrast.png"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "manufacturer",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "Hortisis"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "medida",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "mS/cm"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "name_comun",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "CE del medio"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "place",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "interior"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "timestamp",
            "type" : "DateTime",
            "value" : "2020-01-30T12:24:05.00Z"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "type",
            "type" : "String",
            "value" : "fertigation"
        }
    ]
}
```

Necesito convertir el campo sensor_type a un array con un unico objeto quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
{
   "_id":"15_62",
   "medidas":[
      {
         "_id":"5e3419e468d01013eadb83dc",
         "marca":"Hortisis",
         "modelo":"Estacion",
         "fabricante":"Hortisis",
         "id_station":"15",
         "sensor_type":[
            {
               "name":"15",
               "type":"fertigation",
               "place":"interior",
               "img":"assets/img/contrast.png",
               "name_comun":"Temp. Suelo",
               "medida":"mS/cm"
            }
         ],
         "attrName":"15",
         "attrValue":0.33,
         "recvTimeTs":1580387045,
         "recvTime":"2020-01-30T12:24:05.00Z",
         "id_sensor_station_absolute":"15_62"
      }
   ]
}
```

Como se puede ver realmente es darle formato al campo sensor_type = name : value.

Estoy trabajando con NODEJS y mongoose.

Esta es mi consulta: (en primer lugar busco, ordeno , solo muestro el primer valor y luego con el project doy formato, el problema es que no se como decirle al project poner ese formato si pongo "sensor_type": "$latest.attributes.name") solo muestra los nombres y no se como ponerlo en el formato mencionado.

```
Datagreenhouse.aggregate([
        { "$match": { "id_sensor_station_absolute": { "$in": array3 } } }, // "id_station": { "$in": id_station },
        { "$sort": { "recvTime": -1 } },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": "$id_sensor_station_absolute",
                "latest": { "$first": "$$ROOT" },
            }
        },
        {
            "$project": {
                "_id": 1,
                "id_station": "$latest.id_station",
                //"id_sensor_station_absolute": "$id_sensor_station_absolute",
                "attrName": "$latest.attrName",
                "attrValue": "$latest.attrValue",
                "recvTimeTs": "$latest.recvTimeTs",
                "recvTime": "$latest.recvTime",
                "id_sensor_station_absolute": "$latest.id_sensor_station_absolute",
                "sensor_type": "$latest.attributes"

            }
        }
    ], (err, DatagreenhouseRecuperado) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send({ message: 'Error al realizar la peticion' + err })
        if (!DatagreenhouseRecuperado) return res.status(404).send({ message: 'Error el usuario no existe' })
        res.status(200).send({ DatagreenhouseRecuperado })
    })
```

Gracias por la ayuda. un saludo.

Comment: te recomiendo hacer primero tu funcion en mongodb, luego usa mongoose

Comment: Estoy probando con las dos cosas, pero no consigo obtener la salida deseada...

Comment: Hola. Tiene que ser directamente en mongo? Otro punto. Es posible que actualices a la versión mas reciente de mongodb? Tiene algunas funciones muy interesantes que serian de bastante ayuda.Y por ultimo, la estructura de `sensor_type` cambia ?

Comment: Hola, puedo actualizar a la 3.6. sensor_type por ahora no tengo pensado que cambie la verdad.